# Prior of Bayes rule with three variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I'm having difficulty understanding/accepting this equation I saw in a course I'm doing:

[image]

When I try to derive it using the usual way you derive Bayes rule by equating two ways of writing conditional probability:

$$
P(\theta,X,y) = P(\theta)P(X|\theta)P(y|X,\theta)
$$
$$
P(\theta,X,y) = P(y)P(X|y)P(\theta|X,y)
$$
and going from there, I get

$$
P(\theta|X_{tr}y_{tr}) = \frac{P(y_{tr}|X_{tr},\theta)P(\theta|X_{tr})}{P(y_{tr}|X_{tr})}.
$$

So why does my straightforward derivation disagree with their equation?

Comment: Difficult to know without more context of the situation, but if $\theta$ is, say, a regression coefficient for $y = \theta x + \epsilon$, then $P(\theta \mid X_{tr}) = P(\theta)$ because just knowing $X_{tr}$ tells us nothing about $\theta$, we need to observe $y_{tr}$ too.

Comment: Maybe $\theta$ and $X_{tr}$ are given to be _independent_?

Comment: Indeed your derivation is correct. The equation reported in the article has an additional assumption that $\theta$ and $X_tr$ are independent, which is a standard modelling decision.